# Custom Post Type Pagination For Genesis Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, genesis

Is there any possible to implement the pagination for custom post type in Genesis child theme, I'm using Genesis : 2.0.2 and Wordpress version is : 4.0.

I've tried the following code in my template, but it's not working for me.

```
<?php echo genesis_posts_nav(); ?>
```

And my normal category pagination also not working for me in my genesis child theme.

```
<?php echo genesis_posts_nav(); ?>
```

**My Custom Template Code Here :**

```
<?php 

remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'sk_do_loop' );

function sk_do_loop(){

$args_spotlight_latest = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'spotlight', 'post_status'=>'publish','meta_key' => 'featured_slider','meta_value' => 'true');
$spotlight_posts_latest = new WP_Query($args_spotlight_latest);

/** Content Area **/

if($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){

    while($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){
    $spotlight_posts_latest->the_post();                        
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());   

    ..............
    ..............
    ..............
   }

}

genesis_posts_nav();

}

?>
```

Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use this code , it will sure work, issue with static page

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'sk_do_loop' );

function sk_do_loop(){
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args_spotlight_latest = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'spotlight', 'paged' => $paged);
$spotlight_posts_latest = new WP_Query($args_spotlight_latest);

/** Content Area **/

if($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){

    while($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){
    $spotlight_posts_latest->the_post(); 


    echo "<h1>".the_title()."</h1>";
    the_content();

   }
   previous_posts_link( '« Newer' ); 
 next_posts_link( 'Older »', $spotlight_posts_latest->max_num_pages ); 

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the final code :**

```
<?php

remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'sk_do_loop' );

function sk_do_loop(){

global $wp_query;
$temp_query = $wp_query;

// Fix for the WordPress 3.0 "paged" bug.
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
$paged = intval( $paged );

$args_spotlight_latest = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'spotlight', 'post_status'=>'publish','meta_key' => 'featured_slider','meta_value' => 'true', 'paged' => $paged);
$spotlight_posts_latest = new WP_Query($args_spotlight_latest);
$wp_query = $spotlight_posts_latest;
/** Content Area **/

if($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){

    while($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){
    $spotlight_posts_latest->the_post();                        
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());   

    ..............
    ..............
    ..............
   }

}

genesis_posts_nav();

wp_reset_query();

}
```

?>

It's working great :)